# AWS Lambda connecting DocumentDb instance got MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-documentdb

Got following error logs when trying to connecting lambda to documentdb.

```html
TART RequestId: 0946e4e9-9364-4af2-9802-7ea2d8b946d5 Version: $LATEST
2021-08-18T16:25:11.958Z    0946e4e9-9364-4af2-9802-7ea2d8b946d5    INFO    insideHandler
2021-08-18T16:25:42.296Z    0946e4e9-9364-4af2-9802-7ea2d8b946d5    ERROR   MongoServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN sample-dev-01-instance1.abcde.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:325:38)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'sample-dev-01-instance1.abcde.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  }
}
```

the VPC of lambda is the same as documentdb instance. The nodejs code connects the instance successfully when running in local but has the issue in lambda.

```html
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    console.log("insideHandler");
    const uri = 'mongodb://username:password@sample-dev-01-instance1.abcde.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017';
    const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        ssl: true,
        tlsCAFile: `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`, //Specify the DocDB; cert
        retryWrites: false
    });
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log("connect successfully");
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'connect successfully' })
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
};
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

EAI_AGAIN is a DNS lookup timed out error, means it is a network connectivity error or proxy related error. Can you confirm whether the Lambda function is using the same security group as the DocumentDB cluster?